# Reusable UICollectionViewCell doesn't refreshing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionreusableview

My UICollectionViewCell has a button in storyboard and setting the background image of number of buttons dynamically from document directory creating issues like some buttons background image doesn't refreshing, they hold old image even when i dismiss the controller and load again that controller, the issue still exist. How can solve this issue ?

In My CollectionViewController :

```
- (NSString *)getBackgroundImage:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSArray *indexes = [self.allColors[indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"indexes"];

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@/combimeter_button/combimeter_%ld_%@@2x.png", [self.documentDirectory getDocumentsDirectory], _selectedCar, _selectedCar, (long)[indexes[indexPath.row] integerValue], [self getColorKey:indexPath.section]];
}


- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CustomCollectionViewCell *cell = (CustomCollectionViewCell *) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
    cell.layer.borderColor = [[self getBackgroundColor:indexPath.section] CGColor];
    [cell.cellButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[self getBackgroundImage:indexPath]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.cellButton addTarget:self action:@selector(combimeterButtonDidSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;
}
```

In my custom collectionView Cell :

```
@interface CustomCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *cellButton;

@end

@implementation CustomCollectionViewCell

-(void)prepareForReuse {
    NSLog(@"Is it possible to clear here ? but this method didn't call in my code");
}

@end
```

Comment: wt is your data source for section and rows ?

Comment: I'm getting data from plist file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the problem is that `imageNamed:` caches the image. Try using `imageWithContentsOfFile:` instead.

Comment: Thanks junk_key, you saved my life...:)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing all previous views before creating a new view:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CustomCollectionViewCell *cell = (CustomCollectionViewCell *) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    for (UIView *subview in [cell subviews]) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: No, this is not working, in this case, all the buttons are blank, no background image is showing.